# Is the action of the absolute Frobenius on de Rham cohomology induced by an algebraic map?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, derham-cohomology

Let $X\to \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be a smooth proper morphism with a geometrically connected generic fiber. Assume that the special fiber has an $\mathbb{F}_p$-point.

Via the isomorphism $H^{*}_{\mathrm{cris}}(X_{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{Z}_p)\approx H^{*}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X_{\mathbb{Z}_p})$ the absolute Frobenius of the special fiber induces a map $H^{*}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X_{\mathbb{C}})\to H^*_{\mathrm{dR}}(X_{\mathbb{C}})$. Is this map induced by an algebraic map $X_{\mathbb{C}}\to X_{\mathbb{C}}$?

This seems like a strong condition since if $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a hyperbolic curve there is finitely many algebraic self-maps (any such map is constant or an automorphism) but the mapping class group is infinite.

Comment: For a hyperbolic curve, how does an algebraic self-map act on $H^2(X)$? (What about for a mapping class?) How does Frobenius act on $H^2(X)$?

Comment: Every algebraic self map of an ordinary (i.e. without complex multiplication) elliptic curve over C acts by a scalar on the De-Rham cohomology because its a multiplication by k map of a torus. But the Frobenious can't be scalar (it is of determinant p on H^1_{dR}).

Comment: A different perspective: the crystalline Frobenius will not preserve the Hodge filtration in most cases, and hence can't be induced by an algebraic map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. For a generic elliptic curve E, every algebraic map $E\to E$ is, up to shift by elements of $E$, a multiplication map $[k]\colon E\to E$. In particular, it acts on $H^1_{\mathrm{dR}}(E)$ as multiplication by $k$. But $\mathrm{Fr}$ acts on the 2-dimensional space $H^1(E)$ as a linear map with determinant $p$, and hence can not be scalar.